GA property access management : Can’t add service account
2nd imagehere’s the image I’ve been trying to add a service account and assign role in my Google analytics property access management, but when I enter the email and select the role it says Failed to register users..
I’ve tried creating a new service account, but I still face the same problem, I also tried using AI but still kept encountering the same issue


Can you post a picture of where you are adding it. Where did you get the service account

I’ve added the picture and I got the service account from google cloud console, IAM & Admin section under service account

It looks added to me where are you seeing the error

No not the first one I uploaded the image again, when I try to add the user it say failed to register user

I've added a screen shot to help. I also have this issue currently. I could add another regular email address first.last@hotmail.com but not a Google Cloud service account ga4-sp@lessage-age-111111.iam.gserviceaccount.com (email is not the original but very alike)

FYI, I'm an Administrator of the account I tried to add a user to.

@Stokedout I can reproduce this problem while following the instructions from https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/quickstart-client-libraries. I have two admin accounts I have tested with and both have the issue. I have tried adding the user at the account and property level and get the same error in all cases.
